# How to obtain F# powerpack for F# 3.0

Tags: windows-8, f#, f#-3.0, f#-powerpack

I'm using VS11 Beta on Win 8 Consumer Preview.  After install VS11 Beta I have F# 3.0 SDK installed.  But I'm not able to find a compatible `FSharp.PowerPack.dll` as [CodePlex](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/) only provides PowerPack for F# 2.0.

Any idea how to deal with this?

Answer (score 8):

You can compile the PowerPack sources on your own (against F# 3.0), to make your own copy of the library.

Alternatively, I think a binding redirect in your final foo.exe.config, along the lines of

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9648673/19299

but redirecting 2.0.0.0 (that PowerPack uses) to 4.3.0.0 (in VS11 SDK) will also work.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what Brian said, I think that the easiest way to use functionality from the F# PowerPack is to just copy the source code for the parts that you're using to your project.

The PowerPack library contains quite a wide range of functionality and I typically only use one or two parts. If you're looking for components like lazy list, parallel collections (PLINQ), hash multi-map or async extensions, you can usually just copy one or two files and you don't have to build the whole library.

(Also note that most of the LINQ functionality from F# PowerPack has moved to the F# core library in F# 3.0)

Answer (score 3):

Don Syme has recently uploaded [F# PowerPack 4.0.0.0](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/releases/view/99231) which is compiled against F# 3.0.

There is [an MSI installer](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/downloads/get/578349) for Windows.
There is also [a zip archive](http://FSharpPowerPack-4.0.0.0.zip) which even worked with MonoDevelop 3.0/F# 3.0 when I tried to use it on Mac OS X. So much time and efforts are saved especially when one needs to use `fslex/fsyacc` for parsing.

Comment: How do you install the PowerPack in Mac OS X and Linux?

Comment: The dlls are not signed so I reference the absolute path or copy them to the project folder. I added the path to `fslex/fsyacc` to PATH variable. Of course, you can always compile and install from Github source.

Answer (score 1):

**Update for F# 4.0:**  At this point the F# PowerPack - or at least the remnants thereof - are on [GitHub](https://github.com/fsprojects/powerpack-archive).  The major components have been spun off into their own projects.  ([FsLex/FsYacc](http://fsprojects.github.io/FsLexYacc/) is what brought me here too.)