# How to use pseq in F# 3.0?

Tags: f#, parallel-processing

What is the best way of using PSeq in F# 3.0?

There is no powerpack for F# 3.0 and no evidence I could find of PSeq being included in 3.0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest solution is to copy [PSeq.fs](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/68767#700933) file to your project and compile with F# 3.0.

`PSeq` module is a thin wrapper around PLINQ and has no dependency in F# PowerPack so you can use it independently without any problem.

There are other alternatives:

- Compile [F# PowerPack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/68767) from source against F# 3.0.
- Redirect dll usage in a `exe.config` file.

These techniques are also covered in a similar thread: [How to obtain F# powerpack for F# 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662317/how-to-obtain-f-powerpack-for-f-3-0)

Comment: Thanks - I did what you originally suggest - copy PSeq.fs